# Loop only adds the last result to a list

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to run a small casino roulette betting outcome simulator. As a result I want to understand how big of a bank the casino should have in order not to go bankrupt in relation to the players betting size.
Please see code below:

```
from random import choices

bankroll = 500
bet = 50
lose = -50

population = [bet, lose]
weights = [0.4865, 0.5135]

game_count = 1

winning_game_count = []
bankrupt_game_count = []


for i in range(10000):
    while bankroll != 0 and game_count < 5000:
        result = int(choices(population, weights)[0])
        bankroll -= result
        game_count += 1
        if game_count > 4999:
            winning_game_count.append('won')
        elif bankroll == 0:
            bankrupt_game_count.append('lost')

print(winning_game_count)
print(bankrupt_game_count)
```

I am getting the result of the last iteration only, whereas I want to get the total sum of all games (5000 games) and the number of games where `bankroll` resulted in 0. I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get the result of the last iteration because you only run 1 iteration.
You need to reset the variables that control your loop condition between each iteration:

```
for i in range(10000):
    bankroll=500
    game_count = 1 
    while bankroll != 0 and game_count < 5000:
```